# Unable to do REST PUT operation in OneToMany relation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-repositories

Here's the scenario:

I got two entities

```java
@Entity
@Data
class Project {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="project")
    private List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
class Module {

    @NotEmpty
    String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="project")
    private Project project;
}
```

and there are three types of modules, `Article`, `Footer` and `Header`.

I create a `Project` with collection of three modules:

```
{
  "name" "Test project",
  "modules" : [
    { "type": "Header", "content": "Test title" },
    { "type": "Article", "content": "Bad news!" },
    { "type": "Footer", "content": "Test contact" }
  ]
}
```

I `POST` it under `/projects` and thanks to `@RepositoryRestResource` it all works great. `Project` - `Test project` is now available under `/projects/1`.

But now when I do `PUT` under `/projects/1` with data

```
{
  "name" "Real test project",
  "modules" : [
    { "type": "Header", "content": "Better title" },
    { "type": "Article", "content": "Good news!" },
    { "type": "Article", "content": "Even better news!" },
    { "type": "Article", "content": "Wonderful news!" },
    { "type": "Footer", "content": "phone (00000)" }
  ]
}
```

it always ends up with

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read an object of type class com.example.Project from the request!; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read payload!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target bean of type com.example.Article is not of type of the persistent entity (com.example.Footer)!
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPutForUpdate(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:228) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:194) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:141) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
```

**EDIT**

Looks like the issue is already being investigated https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1012

Comment: Have you also tried doing a `POST` request with multiple Articles? If so does that work?

Comment: @slawek, whta do mean by "I POST it under /projects and thanks to RepositoryRestResource it all works great. Project - Test project is now available under /projects/1"? Please provide code of ur Modules entity?  Also the controller class.

Comment: Your bidirectionalOneToMany mapping is wrong. Start by fixing that. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional